# MacBook Pro running Tiger 10.4 erase start up disk

Tags: macbook-pro

I do not have the original disks but the computer has been upgraded to Snow Leopard.  I have the Snow Leopard 10.6.3 disks but the computer will not allow the disks access to my startup disk.  I need to erase all and restore the computer to its original state so I can sell it. I have talked to Apple and they say the machine is too old and they do not have the original disks available.

Answer (score 1):

If the disks you have are not full retail disks [grey background rather than white, quite often], then they may not work on all machines, but only those they were designed for at the time.

Apple still sell the Snow Leopard DVD - http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard - though whether it's really worth $19 these days is debatable.

If you know anyone with an Apple Developer account, Snow Leopard is available as a disk image, directly downloadable from [Download Mac OS X 10.6 10a432 DVD image (direct link from Apple)](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Mac_OS_X/mac_os_x_version_10.6_snow_leopard_build_10a432/mac_os_x_v10.6_build_10a432_user_dvd.dmg), for burning to DVD.